# how to show objects only in render preview

Tags: modeling, rendering, 3d-view

I am working on an interior scene where the walls are blocking my view. However, i cannot just hide them because I am arranging some objects in the room that are casting shadows on the wall. So I need to see the wall at least in render preview. Is there a way to hide the walls in all views except the render peview?

Answer (score 1):

You could disable an object's ray visibility so that it isn't visible in Cycles render preview but still visible in other viewports modes and final render. But not the other way around.

[image: ray visibility]

Answer (score 0):

I just used the "x-ray mode" next to the viewport modes. That solves the issue basically.